# Tabhost inside a SherlockFragment using ViewPageIndicator

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, actionbarsherlock

So I have 3 Sherlock Fragments setup and working fine with ViewPageIndicator. What I'd like to do now is put a TabHost inside one of the Fragments so that it displays 2 separate tabs (at the bottom). I believe this means I need to have 2 more Fragments to put inside the 3rd Fragment controlled by the TabHost.

Considering the TabHost needs to be created inside a Fragment, I'm not sure how to properly create it.

Here is the code for the Fragment I've gotten working from [this tutorial](http://droidista.blogspot.com/2012/08/making-actionbarsherlock-and.html), which I've tried to update to add the TabHost unsuccessfully:

TestFragment3.java

```
public class TestFragment3 extends SherlockFragment {
private String mContent = "none";

public static TestFragment3 newInstance(String text) {
    TestFragment3 fragment = new TestFragment3();

    // Supply num input as an argument.
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(KEY_TAB_NUM, text);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
    String text = getString(R.string.tab_page_num) + mContent;
    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(text);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   mContent =  getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getString(KEY_TAB_NUM) : "none";
}

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

private static final String[] TAB_TITLES = new String[] { "This", "Is", "A", "ViewPager" };

TestFragmentAdapter mAdapter;
    ViewPager mPager;
    PageIndicator mIndicator;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.simple_tabs);

    mAdapter = new TestFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mIndicator = (TabPageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
}

class TestFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {     
    private int mCount = TAB_TITLES.length;

    public TestFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return TestFragment.newInstance(String.valueOf(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mCount;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return TAB_TITLES[position];
    }
}
}
```

Do I need to create a new SherlockFragmentActivity and add the 2 additional SherlockFragments to that  TabHost? If so, how do I setup the MainActivity with 3 Fragments to use another Activity, not a Fragment, for its 3rd Fragment?

I'm getting this error for trying to put a Fragment within a Fragment...

```
11-14 19:10:54.271: E/AndroidRuntime(2812): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions
11-14 19:10:54.271: E/AndroidRuntime(2812):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1388)
11-14 19:10:54.271: E/AndroidRuntime(2812):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:431)
11-14 19:10:54.271: E/AndroidRuntime(2812):     at com.example.demolistview.EventInviteesFragment$TabManager.onTabChanged(EventInviteesFragment.java:152)
11-14 19:10:54.271: E/AndroidRuntime(2812):     at android.widget.TabHost.invokeOnTabChangeListener(TabHost.java:391)
11-14 19:10:54.271: E/AndroidRuntime(2812):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:376)
11-14 19:10:54.271: E/AndroidRuntime(2812):     at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:236)
...
...
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In regards to this question:

> Considering the TabHost needs to be created inside a Fragment, I'm not
>   sure how to properly create it.

If you look at the latest support demos they have an example of what you are trying to implement. They can be downloaded through the SDK Manager.

This is how they are nesting a tab host within a fragment. The setup is using the Child FragmentManager.

```
public class FragmentTabsFragmentSupport extends Fragment {
    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mTabHost = new FragmentTabHost(getActivity());
        mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.fragment1);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("Simple"),
                FragmentStackSupport.CountingFragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("contacts").setIndicator("Contacts"),
                LoaderCursorSupport.CursorLoaderListFragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("custom").setIndicator("Custom"),
                LoaderCustomSupport.AppListFragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("throttle").setIndicator("Throttle"),
                LoaderThrottleSupport.ThrottledLoaderListFragment.class, null);

        return mTabHost;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        mTabHost = null;
    }
}
```

I also created a small example which can be found at: https://github.com/marsucsb/nested-fragments

Comment: this is perfect! I struggled with it at first because the android-support-v4.jar didnt update in my project automatically when I downloaded through the SDK manager. However, since there is no XML layout to define the tabwidget, how can I align it at the bottom?

Comment: I havent tried it yet but im guessing that you can define the TabHost inside of a xml layout file and use the LayoutInflater in onCreateView to inflate the layout and then u can find the TabHost by id and add the needed fragments.

Comment: No luck at all. Even if I inflate the layout and grab the tabhost from the inflated layout, the tabs remain at the top.

Comment: - Did you have any luck getting this to work? I am still unable to position the nested tabs at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Did not tested it, but should be something like this

```
TabFragment extends SherlockFragment {
TabHost mTabHost;
    TabManager mTabManager;

mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
                 mTabHost.setup();

                 mTabManager = new TabManager(this.getActivity(), mTabHost, R.id.realtabcontent);

                 mTabManager.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("first").setIndicator("First", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_first_tab)), FirstFragment.class  , null);

                 mTabManager.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("second").setIndicator("Second", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_second_tab)), SecondFragment.class  , null);
 public static class TabManager implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener {
            private final FragmentActivity mActivity;
            private final TabHost mTabHost;
            private final int mContainerId;
            private final HashMap<String, TabInfo> mTabs = new HashMap<String, TabInfo>();
            TabInfo mLastTab;

            static final class TabInfo {
                private final String tag;
                private final Class<?> clss;
                private final Bundle args;
                private Fragment fragment;

                TabInfo(String _tag, Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
                    tag = _tag;
                    clss = _class;
                    args = _args;
                }
            }

            static class DummyTabFactory implements TabHost.TabContentFactory {
                private final Context mContext;

                public DummyTabFactory(Context context) {
                    mContext = context;
                }


                public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                    View v = new View(mContext);
                    v.setMinimumWidth(0);
                    v.setMinimumHeight(0);
                    return v;
                }
            }

            public TabManager(FragmentActivity activity, TabHost tabHost, int containerId) {
                mActivity = activity;
                mTabHost = tabHost;
                mContainerId = containerId;
                mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
            }

            public void addTab(TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
                tabSpec.setContent(new DummyTabFactory(mActivity));
                String tag = tabSpec.getTag();

                TabInfo info = new TabInfo(tag, clss, args);

                // Check to see if we already have a fragment for this tab, probably
                // from a previously saved state.  If so, deactivate it, because our
                // initial state is that a tab isn't shown.
                info.fragment = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
                if (info.fragment != null && !info.fragment.isDetached()) {
                    FragmentTransaction ft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    ft.detach(info.fragment);
                    ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
                }

                mTabs.put(tag, info);
                mTabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
            }


            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
                TabInfo newTab = mTabs.get(tabId);
                if (mLastTab != newTab) {
                    FragmentTransaction ft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    if (mLastTab != null) {
                        if (mLastTab.fragment != null) {
                            ft.detach(mLastTab.fragment);
                        }
                    }
                    if (newTab != null) {
                        if (newTab.fragment == null) {
                            newTab.fragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity,
                                    newTab.clss.getName(), newTab.args);
                            ft.add(mContainerId, newTab.fragment, newTab.tag);
                        } else {
                            ft.attach(newTab.fragment);
                        }
                    }

                    mLastTab = newTab;
                    ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
                    mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
                }
            }
        }
}
```

And your frament layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

<TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

     <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">



        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

        </FrameLayout>

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
            android:background="#333333" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         />


        </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Ahhhh, ok. So it looks like you just need to add tabs to the fragment via @JakeWharton 's TabManager class using the DummyTab. I'll give this a shot!

Comment: Yes it is pretty standart approach. If you look at Sherlock's tab bar source code. You will notice the same implementation of fragments tab bar

Comment: So I'm getting an error for a recursive entry to executePendingTransactions... Are Fragments within Fragments not allowed? Updated code above

Comment: It was discouraged to nest fragments before revision 11 of the Android Support Library. Update your Support Library to revision 11 and use the newly introduced Fragment method "getChildFragmentManager". Check out this link for more information http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments

Comment: So how would I update this code to use the last line of code above in the `onTabChanged` method?  ...   `mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
`

Comment: You shoul not put them inside fragments. Shou should put them inside activity from fragment. Thats why i wrote  mTabManager = new TabManager(this.getActivity(), mTabHost, R.id.realtabcontent); Also you sould perform all instantiations in onActivityCreated() not on onCreate() And yes. Nested fragments are not allowed

Comment: @Greensy I dont understand. I have a MainActivity with 3 Fragments being controlled by a ViewPager. Inside the 3rd Fragment, I want a tabhost with 2 tabs (also fragments). Can I do that with API v17 and the updated support library?

Comment: @Marco How would I update the code above in the TabManager class to use `getChildFragmentManager`?